# Specify automatically the height and weight of the images

Tags: images

I just did a GTmetrix test for my website to check how it's going, and I noticed that I have many images without height & width size specified.

So I start thinking about a Wordpress function that get the height and width of the current image and echo it.

I found it but didn't work that s why I m here to share with you the peace of code I made and see if you can help me please.

```
<img src="<?php echo aq_resize(wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ), 120, 90, true); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>/>
```

Here is the result when i use this code

```
<img src="http://xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/marina-120x90.jpg" alt="marina : La construction de la plus haute tour d’Afrique débutera en juin" width="" height="/&gt;

                                &lt;/figure&gt;
                                &lt;div class='text'&gt;
                                    &lt;h3&gt;
                                        &lt;a href=" http:="" xxxx.com="" marina-la-construction-de-la-plus-haute-tour-dafrique-debutera-en-juin="" "="">
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your code for image, use this following.

```
<?php $thumb_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 120, 90, true ); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $thumb_image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_html( get_the_title() ); ?>" width="<?php echo $thumb_image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $thumb_image[2]; ?>" />
```

Let me explain a little what it's doing. We are returning PHP array of attachment image with WordPress function [`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src).

This PHP array containing: (from Codex)

- [0] => url
- [1] => width
- [2] => height
- [3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.

So we added those values in our image tag.
Try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: This will use the closest available size, but with `add_image_size` you can define a new image size that's exactly what's needed

Comment: Actually I was about to add a pre-define size instead of `120, 90` in `wp_get_attachment_image_src` but OP has these values so I guess he wanted to use that. But your suggestion is good and I hope OP follows.

Comment: Thanks for ur Answers guys just about Robert solution i will have to dont use "aq_resize" what can be a probléme for my theme and Tom can u tell us more about ur solution ? Thank you